# Tag fix request: [mastersummoner] to [master-summoner]

Tags: support, status-norepro, tags

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39451/ways-to-solve-balance-problems-with-a-master-summoner) has the tag [mastersummoner](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mastersummoner), which should be [master-summoner](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-summoner) per the guidelines that spaces should appears as dashes in tag names.

Seems stupid to ask a mod for something so simple, but the site won't let me fix this tag:

> You are attempting to create the tag [master-summoner]; however the tag [mastersummoner] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

(This is assuming that we need the tag at all, which I'm unsure of but was going to leave for someone who's more Pathfinder-y to worry about.)

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest removing the tag. I don't think we need tags for specific classes, so tags for an ultra-specific alternate class feature of a non-core class? Seems excessive.

Comment: I concur, no need for that one.

Comment: I removed this tag already, since I didn't even think to check meta about it; seemed obvious to me that it shouldn't exist. In the future I'll be a little more conscientious, but looks like it was the right thing.

Comment: I'd tend to agree that we don't need class-specific tags, but we do have a pile of them already, like [[tag:wizard]] and such.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Class specific is OK IMO, subclass is a bit too niche unless we get tens of questions on a particular one

Comment: @waxeagle The problem is that if we nuke the tag now, and later get dozens of questions on it, this particular question will be lost unless someone actively goes searching and retagging it.

Comment: @lisardggY not a big deal IMO, it still has [tag:summoner]